# issue with floating point precision js

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am experiencing the following bug in my JS.

`(1.001 * Math.pow(10, 3))`

Instead of returning `1001` this returns `1000.99999999`. I am trying to eradicate this bug and have been looking at using this [big.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/) library.

I am unsure what to do to fix this issue.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var x = new Big(10);
(1.001 * x.pow(3));
```

This produces the same bug as without the library.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3993662)

Comment: @baao thanks! I understand it is an issue, my problem is I am unable to implement a solution

Comment: Just posted it because you said it's a bug, which it isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Big.js that way, I think you have to forget using conventional operators :

```js
console.log(Big(1.001).times(Big(10).pow(3)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big.js/3.2.0/big.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works here, but when I try that in the console it returns a `Big` object

Comment: When I use `toPrecision` it works. however, when ive just put your answer into my code and I get returned a Big object. why am i seeing a diff value to you do you know? you get the right value but do not use `toPrecision`

Comment: Because I call `console.log` which will itself call `toString` on the `Big` object.